# How to divide frame by two parts in LyX?

Tags: beamer, lyx, presentations

I have a long experience with LaTeX. However, I am beginner with LyX and there is some things that differ. I start to make presentation and I can not do such very simple thing as dividing frame into two or more columns. I understand that I should do as follows:

1. Click to columns
2. Then click to column
3. Defined width
4. Than do something about paragraph. This part I do not understand

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to the layout textbox (the one in the upper left that says "Standard" if you are not in any special layout, use alt+p  as a shortcut to open it).
2. Select Columns (top aligned).
3. Press return.
4. Go to the layout textbox and select "Column".
5. If on LyX <= 2.2.x, press tab in order to nest this column within the columns environment. With LyX >= 2.3.x, this step is unnecessary thanks to the new AutoNests layout feature.
6. Press ctrl + l (or Insert > TeX Code) to put a width (e.g. `.4\textwidth`).
7. Press return.
8. Write some text for this column, using any desired layout (e.g. "Standard").
9. Insert another column (see step 4).

Note that starting with LyX 2.1 you will be able to access the Beamer manual by going to Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer.

Below is a `.lyx` example file (taken from the 2.1 manual):

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass beamer
\begin_preamble
% We use the "Berkeley" theme with a 3.45em-wide side bar on the left
\usetheme[left,width=3.45em]{Berkeley}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format pdf2
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Presentations with Beamer and LyX
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subtitle
An Introduction to the Basics
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
The LyX Team
\end_layout

\begin_layout Date
V.
 2.0.x
\end_layout

\begin_layout TitleGraphic
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename ../../lyxbuilds/master/repo/lib/doc/clipart/mobius.eps
    lyxscale 30
    scale 10

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout BeginFrame
Columns
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Sometimes it is useful to divide a presentation into columns
\end_layout

\begin_layout ColumnsTopAligned

\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Column
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

.4
\backslash
textwidth
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
To do this, first select 
\begin_inset Flex Structure
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Columns
\end_layout

\end_inset

 (note the plural) to start the columns
\end_layout

\begin_layout Pause

\end_layout

\begin_layout Column
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

.4
\backslash
textwidth
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
And then, in the following paragraph, select 
\begin_inset Flex Structure
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Column
\end_layout

\end_inset

 (singular) to start a specific column
\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Pause

\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset VSpace defskip
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Note:
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
In the 
\begin_inset Flex Structure
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Column
\end_layout

\end_inset

 (singular) environment, you need to specify the width using LaTeX syntax
 (but also something like 
\begin_inset Quotes eld
\end_inset

3.5cm
\begin_inset Quotes erd
\end_inset

 will work)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
Any (singular) 
\begin_inset Flex Structure
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Column
\end_layout

\end_inset

 must be nested to the (plural) 
\begin_inset Flex Structure
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Columns
\end_layout

\end_inset

.
 Likewise, column content can be any paragraph style that is nested to a
 singular 
\begin_inset Flex Structure
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Column
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout EndFrame

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Tried this on LyX 2.3.4.2 on Ubuntu.  when I pres tab in step 5, I get command disabled and I don't know how to re-enable it or what the command is.  Any thoughts

Comment: @LenB Thanks for the comment. On LyX 2.3.x, that step is not necessary since after you press return it should be automatically nested. I updated the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded after trying a long time in Lyx 2.3.5.2

1. select "ColumnCenterAligned" ;
   [image]
2. press "Enter";
3. select "Column" and input the width, for example "5cm";
4. press "Alt" + "Enter" and input width again, then move the cursor to precious line and press "Alt" + "Enter"

[image]

5. don't move cursor, select "Block" (or others) then you can edit anything you want.
6. when you want to edit the second column, just move the cursor to the end of the second "Start column (increase deapth!), witdth: 5cm" and press "Alt" + "Enter", then repeat 5.
   [image]